# Bootstrap 3 tab('show') on long page hides tabs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using el.tab('show') to show a bootstrap 3 tab, it works but when content of the tab is large, tabs are not visible anymore because of page scrolling (this is not the same behavior as if clicking on the tab itself). Any idea how to workaround this? Thanks.

*Update*: here is a sample code. Tab One is displayed by default, and clicking on the "Go To Tab 2" anchor moves to tab 2 which contains a large page. Problem is that top tabs are not visible anymore after the click as bottom of the page embedded in tab 2 is shown.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a href="#tab_one" data-toggle="tab">Tab One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab_two" data-toggle="tab">Tab Two</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
<div id="tab_one" class="tab-pane fade in">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tab_two" onClick="jQuery('.nav-tabs a[href=#tab_two]').tab('show')">Go to Tab 2</a> </li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="tab_two" class="tab-pane fade in">
<p>content of tab 2, long page </p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Include some code please so we know what need fixing.

Comment: I updated the initial post with sample code.

Comment: hmm, I'm not getting that problem with your code...example http://jsfiddle.net/dt9gj/

Comment: Ok so the problem might not be that the bottom of page is shown, but simply that the tabs are hidden when clicking on the link. (this is what is happening at  jsfiddle.net/dt9gj too). I would like the tab to remain visible, same as if I was clicking on tab 2 instead of the link.

Comment: I see. I was missing the point about clicking the link within tab1 content to get to tab 2, as opposed to clicking on tab2 directly. And now see that the page scrolls (well, jumps) such that the tabs are above the view. Would making the tabs position:fixed work for you? Or do you need them to be relative position when not being clicked ?

Comment: I tried with position:fixed but then I can no more scroll the content of the large page in tab 2 (but it fixes the tab disappearing issue though). The behavior I need is when clicking on the link, to have the exactly same thing as if I was clicking on tab 2 directly: the tabs do not disappear and the page can be scrolled fine.

Answer (score 0):

found a way around the problem, but well, it is not pretty:

```
jQuery('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    setTimeout( function (e) {
       window.scrollTo(0,0);
     }, 1);
});
```